# Using a library that is wrongly licensed

Tags: gpl-2

Let's say there are 3 people Q A Z . Q makes a GPL library.  A uses  it and licensed it under the MIT licence purposefully.   Z uses A's library in a proprietary, paid-for library and distributes it with over a million downloads when Q realizes and files an infringement case against A and then Z has also infringed indirectly.  However Z cannot apply GPL to his code as it would be a commercial disaster.  What will Z do?

Comment: If Z won't release under GPL, then what possible answer other than *Immediately cease distribution and give refunds to all affected users* are you expecting?

Comment: But is it in this case really Z's fault that he did not reverify?Shouldn't all the burden be on A?Z just used code under the license he found.

Comment: Z's lack of deliberate copyright violation until now is what will likely save him/her from punitive damages.  But now (s)he knows.  If (s)he continues to distribute code in violation, or allow code to be used by his/her customers in violation, that defence will disappear.  I ask again, what sort of answer were you hoping for?  That some kind of GPL exception might appear out of thin air, so Z could continue trading without interruption?

Comment: So you mean that the only thing Z can do is cease distribution.However just asking in case Z had promised some long time support to his customers which is no longer possible can Z ask reparations from A?

Comment: Cease distribution *and refund all affected customers*, yes.  As for A's liability, Z didn't pay A anything for the code in the first place; why on earth should A be financially liable?  Here's the rub: Z made a business out of selling other people's work.  It's Z's job to **bend over backwards** to ensure (s)he has the rights to do that.  Z failed to do so, and must now face the consequences.

Comment: So can Z now make a new piece of software removing the GPL code and distribute it?

Comment: That's a completely different question, please don't use comments to ask new questions.

Comment: one last question will an agreement stating that Z  has  not libality with the customer save Z from refund?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 6):

Z will **either** release his/her work under GPL, **or** (s)he will immediately cease distribution and refund all his/her affected customers for the code which they have paid to use but may no longer use.  Those are the options available (**edit:** approaching Q for a commercial licence is, as Felix G points out below, another option, though one that I consider very unlikely to succeed).

As covered in comments above, Z didn't pay A for the code that A mistakenly made available under MIT; indeed, A may well not have the faintest idea that Z is using A's code in this way.  So it is very unlikely A would have any liability.

If Z was selling a product with a clear disclaimer that the customer bought it at their own risk and Z had no idea whether the customer was entitled to use it, then I suppose it's possible that Z would be protected from an obligation to refund his/her customers.  But (a) it's jurisdictionally-dependent, (b) it's also off-topic for OS.SE, and (c) why would anybody buy a product under those terms in the first place?

At the end of the day, Z has decided to make a business out of selling someone else's work.  If you're going to do that, you need to **bend over backwards** to ensure that you have the right to do it.  Z failed to ensure that, and is enjoying the consequences.

Comment: I'd like to add that there technically is a third option: Z could try to ask Q for a commercial license. Of course, Q might not want to do that, or they might not be able to even if they wanted (if there are other contributors and the project doesn't have a CLA/CTA)

Comment: @FelixG that is a very good point, and thank you for making it.  I regard it as vanishingly unlikely that Q would agree, since people who use the GPL generally intend their work to remain open.  Even if Q did, the fact that a million copies have already been sold is going to have a serious effect on the price.  But it is still an option, so thank you again for bringing it up.

Comment: How about any of these other potential options (practical or otherwise): • Z removing the library and writing their own equivalent (taking great care not to use or even see the original code); • commissioning such a replacement from another company; • refactoring their product to use the original GPL library without linking with it; • releasing their product without the library and requiring their customers to obtain and install it; • approaching Q in the hope of getting an LGPL version (which might be more acceptable than a commercial licence).

Comment: @gidds it's a bit late for Z not to see the original code, wouldn't you say?  The second option has nothing to do with free software, the third I don't understand, the fourth doesn't remove the GPL obligation (still a derivative work), the fifth Felix already suggested in effect (and I still think is highly unlikely).